# Helper method with accumulators in Scala

Tags: scala, helper, accumulator

Below is an example used to illustrate how to use immutable variables. (1) What function is this method performing and (2) which portion is considered the accumulator?

```
def fib(n: Int): Int = {
  def fibIter(i: Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int =
    if (i == n) a else fibIter(i+1, b, a+b)
  fibIter(0, 0, 1)
 }
```

Comment: Whats the question ?

Comment: This is just one of the hundreds of ways to express the Fibonacci series. Both `a` and `b` are used to calculate/accumulate the previous & current (or current & next) in the series. `i` is a counter, counting the recursions needed to reach the requested level (`n` recursions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @jwvh in his comment, this is a function for computing the nth term of the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

This particular implementation is tail recursive and uses the inner function `fibIter` as an "accumulator." Often in order to code a tail recursive implementation of a recursive function, it is useful to define an inner tail recursive function that accumulates the desired result. The outer function will the call this inner function with some default params. Sometimes this inner function is called "accumulate" or "go" or "loop", etc.

Here would be my preferred implementation of a Fibonacci similar to the above...

```
def fibonacci(n: Int): Int = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def iterate(i: Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int =
    if (i == n) a else iterate(i+1, b, a+b)
  iterate(0, 0, 1)
}
```

...here I prefer to call the inner function `iterate` because this is a more accurate description of what the function is doing (i.e., it isn't really accumulating anything).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've learned much from this function now.

Comment: @davidpugh Thanks a lot. I've learned much from this function now. 1) It is a Fibonacci sequence -- thanks for the link.  2) fibIter probably stands for fibonacci iterator.  3) n is how many members of the sequence you want; i is the counter to get there. 4) b/a track or "accumulate" the return value 5) a+b/b accumulate the next number in the sequence. Understanding that it's Fibonacci is key. 6) The inner function can be called an Accumulator